# Dead-zone Modeled as Switching System

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, nonlinear-system, convex-geometry

**SUMMARY**

Consider the $\mathbb{dz}$ function, modeled as a switching system
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{dz}(w(t)) = 
\left\{\begin{matrix}
-\rho, & w(t) > \rho \\
0, & \left | w(t) \right | \leq \rho \\
\rho, & w(t) < -\rho \\ 
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation}

When $|w(t)| < \rho$, the function is inside a symmetric set defined by
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{S} = \left \{ w(t) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}; w(t)^{\top}w(t) \leq \rho^{2} \right \}
\end{equation}

**PROBLEM**

My problem is the argument of dead-zone, which is in norm form as follows
\begin{equation}
w(t) = \left \| x(t)\right \|_{G}^{2} \Rightarrow x(t)^{\top}Gx(t)
\end{equation}

I need to convert the norm in a product form like
\begin{equation}
x(t)^{\top}Gx(t) \xrightarrow[magic]{} Sx(t)
\end{equation}

**TRIED SOLUTION**

I've tried to apply Cholesky decomposition
\begin{equation}
x(t)^{\top}Gx(t) \Rightarrow x(t)^{\top}G_1^{\top}G_1x(t) \Rightarrow |G_1x(t)|
\end{equation}

From that point, I didn't find a mathematical way to get $Sx(t)$. Is there a way to work on that problem ?

Comment: Is your $\operatorname{dz}$ an $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ function? What does $w(t)<-\rho$ mean? is it elementwise?

Comment: It is not clear what the question is. Do you want to represent $x^\top Gx$ as $(S x)^\top(S x)$ and ar looking for $S$? If so, it requires some assumptions on $G$.

Comment: $\mathbb{dz}$ is $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I want to represent $x^{\top}Gx$ as $Sx$ only and I'm searching for $S$. Otherwise, I cannot represent the symmetrical set $\mathbb{S}$, which it should look like $|Sx|$, but with norm is $| \left \| x \right \|_{G}^{2}|$

Comment: Then the definition of the set $S$ is unclear as $w(t)$ is a scalar.